# how to get numeric values after special character in a string in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my pipeline I have a variable `abd` with value "`xyz #123`".
I need to get only numeric value after special character `#`,
How do I achieve this in Jenkins Pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Groovy fairly simply (if your string always matches that pattern):

```
abc.substring(abc.indexOf('#') + 1, abc.length())
```

That will give you the string 123.